# Waiting in a Django View For a Webhook or Timeout

Tags: python, heroku, async-await, django-views, whatsapi

I am using WhatsApp official API to send messages to customers. I want to send them a reminder message if they have not replied during a certain period of time (a couple of hours more or less). In other words, I will send a message and wait for a certain period of time for their response. If they respond, no reminder message is needed. If they don't, I will send them a reminder message. WhatsApp API sends webhook notifications when they reply.

How do I implement that in a Django view? I am thinking of creating an async process/thread each time I want to wait, and handle the timeout condition in that process somehow. Is this the right approach? I think that would be costly in terms of server time used, but I am not sure. If this is the right approach, please show some pseudo-code on how it can be done.

I will be deploying my app on Heroku.

Your answer is much appreciated..

Comment: I don't think that handling it with Django is a good idea. It would be better if look for a timed email server.